# how to visualise and delete trailing newline at the end of file in vim\nvim

Tags: vim, neovim

Sometimes I need to edit files which should not end with a newline.

However vim\nvim by default do not visualise in any way the newline character at the end of file. Therefore I am not able to:

1. visually confirm if the file has a newline character at the end or not
2. remove that character

Are there any setting which would allow me to see the tailing newline character and edit it in the same way as any other characters?

For example, after create 2 files as follows:

```bash
echo test > file-with-newline
echo -n test > file-without-newline
```

opening first one with `nvim file-with-newline` shows:

```
test
~
~
file-with-newline
```

opening second one with `nvim file-without-newline` shows:

```
test
~
~
file-without-newline
```

Navigating with the cursor to the end of line in either case yields the same result (the cursor stops after last visible character: `t`). There is no way to tell if the newline is there or not, let alone remove it using familiar commands used to remove ordinary characters (or newlines within the file).

Answer (score 2):

> if the file has a newline character at the end or not

```
:set eol?
endofline
```

> remove that character

```
:set noeol nofixeol
:update
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Matt!

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the option `:help 'list'`:

```
:set list
```

to show that "newline character" as a `$` at the end of the line (among other things):

[image: list]

Note, however, that the option doesn't make the character "editable" in any way.

Comment: And FWIW, make sure you are not confusing "newline" and "new line".